# Get date and time from mongodb document _id field

Tags: mongodb

Is it a normal practice to get date and time from document _id, so i don't need to add additional "date" field to my document? Сan _id change for some reason?

Comment: +1. You have to be careful since the `_id` field isn't necessarily a MongoId object, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This practice is fine. In fact, many of the 10gen supported drivers have some method of extracting the "created date" from the `ObjectId()`/`MongoID()`.

> Сan _id change for some reason?

The major caveat is that you must use IDs generated by MongoDB for this to work.

There are cases where you may have a more appropriate unique ID. In this cases you will not be using Mongo's ID and will therefor need to store the created date on your own.