# Use Date as the ID in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, logging, mongoose

Intending to log use of the API (user/route/params/time) in a Heroku/Node/Express/Mongodb web app, to allow various analytics (who/what/when/how often).  One way I can think of is to push those to MongoDB.

Mongo will generate an ID automatically, and I see that it's possible to [extract the created time from the autogenerated ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021802/get-date-and-time-from-mongodb-document-id-field), but since the time stamp is all I want, now I wonder if I can use the date **as** the ID?

This seems to work, and the timestamps seem granular enough (`"_id" : ISODate("2012-11-30T21:18:24.484Z")`) that they'll be unique.  Is this okay or just asking for an "ID not unique" error just when things get going?

```
var apilogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({            
  _id: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  userId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false},
  route: {type: String, required: false}
})
```

[Get date and time from mongodb document _id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021802/get-date-and-time-from-mongodb-document-id-field)

Comment: Unless you can guarantee your timestamps are always unique, this will eventually give you trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what johnny said, wouldnt recommend that. especially when you are using it for logging user actions. (it is possible that 2 users do an action at the same millisecond, and now your id isnt unique anymore)

check out [node-uuid](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid/) if you are on node.js and want your id to contain a timestamp